# JVMCFRE003 bad major version; class=org/postgresql/Driver, offset=6 while connecting db2 to postgres

Tags: java, postgresql, db2

Please help me to resolve this issue.. I am trying to connect postgres from Db2  using  `InfoSphere Federation Server`:

Getting error:

> JVMCFRE003 bad major version; class=org/postgresql/Driver, offset=6

I am using JDK 1.8, Postgres 12.0, jar -- postgresql-42.2.11.jar

```
CREATE SERVER JCSERV TYPE JDBC VERSION '12.0' WRAPPER JDBC  OPTIONS (DRIVER_PACKAGE 'C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_241\lib\ext\postgresql-42.2.11.jar', DRIVER_CLASS 'org.postgresql.Driver',  URL 'jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/SCOPEDB', JDBC_LOG 'Y');

CREATE USER MAPPING FOR SANAGARW SERVER JCSERV OPTIONS (REMOTE_AUTHID 'postgres',REMOTE_PASSWORD '****');
```

I have created the server with different postgres driver jar files. but its giving same issue with all the driver. I could not find the actual root cause of this issue.

Comment: Do you have mutiple JDK or JVM/jre versions installed on your Windows workstation? Ensure that the only `java` that is on the system and user PATH variable is the one that you *think* you are using.

Comment: What's the result of the following command after setting correct `/full_path/`? 
`eval db2jh=~${DB2INSTANCE}/sqllib/java/jdk64/bin; ${db2jh}/javap -verbose -cp /full_path/postgresql-42.2.11.jar org.postgresql.Driver | grep "major"; ${db2jh}/java -version`

Comment: The Windows version of the question above is: `"%DB2PATH%\java\jdk\bin\javap" -verbose -cp "full_path\postgresql-42.2.11.jar" org.postgresql.Driver | findstr "major"` and `"%DB2PATH%\java\jdk\bin\java" -version`